# How to fix a straight line plot of a logistic map in R?

Tags: r, plot

The logistic map (a map is a function that takes its value at any time step to its value at the next time step) is a model that has its roots in the prediction of animal population sizes. It has become famous, in part, due to special cases of its parameterization that exhibit surprising chaotic behavior. The logistic map equation is

x<sub>i+1</sub> = rx<sub>i</sub>(1 - x<sub>i</sub>)

where x<sub>i</sub> ∈ [0,1] is the value ratio of current population size to maximum possible size at time i, x<sub>i</sub>+1 is the ratio at the next generation and r is the driving rate, representing animal reproduction and death. For r < 3.5 the population eventually reaches a stable size or will oscillate between a set of fixed values. However, if r > 3.5 then the system destabilizes and exhibits chaotic behavior!

That is background or context for the following problem statement:

Generate a set of points S = {r, x} where, for each r ∈ [1.0, 4.1] by increments of 0.001025 there will be a sequence of x<sub>i</sub> values for i = 0,...,16. So, for each r value there will be 17 x<sub>i</sub> values. Use x<sub>0</sub> = 0.01. Depending on your implementation, you may find the `rbind` function useful. It may take a few seconds for the code to run since it will generate a lot of points in S. No more than 10 lines of R code.

Admittedly, this is a lab assignment; however, I am not a student in the class. I am learning R, and I am trying to work through the online assignments and come up with a solution myself. I have tried to create the set of points to plot, and based on manual verification of a few points, the set looks accurate.

```
for(j in c(0:3024)) {
    rm(x)
    x <- 1:17
    x[1] <- 0.01
    r <- 1 + (j * 0.001025)
    for(i in c(1:(17-1))) {
        x[i+1] <- r *x[i]  * (1 - x[i])
    }
    if (j==0) {
        binded <- cbind(r,x)
    } else {
        binded <- rbind(binded, cbind(r,x))
    }
}
```

When I invoke `plot(binded, pch='.')` RStudio displays the result as a straight line. So I am unsure if I am using plot correctly, or even if I am generating all the points correctly. If I decrease the maximum value of `j` to something less than 2000, you will see a plot; it is just when the `j` value iterates up to 3024 that you only plot a straight line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your code is correct, what happens is when time exceeds 4, the of iterations are widely unstable and are going to -infinity.  This large variation in the y value is compressing the scale and making the plot look like a flat line.

Cutting off the tail end of the matrix makes a very interesting plot:

```
plot(binded[-which(binded[,2]<0),], pch=".")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to plot the entire matrix, consider manually setting your y-axis limits to [0,1]. This way, the plot won't be stretched down to `-1e24`.

As an added bonus, here's a version in a different plotting library that has points colored by `i`.

[image: plot]